# In React JS how do we decide whether to choose contextAPI or Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

In React js how do we decide whether to choose context API or Redux?

Comment: ok I will close it.

Comment: Duplicate question. original posts are
[Redux VS Context API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046369/redux-vs-context-api/64048180#64048180) or [React Context vs React Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568073/react-context-vs-react-redux-when-should-i-use-each-one)