# React Topic: Context vs Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, frontend

What are the considerations I should be thinking of when it comes to choosing whether to use contexts to manage states in my front end vs using a state management system like Redux? Pros and cons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redux VS Context API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046369/redux-vs-context-api)

Comment: [React Context vs React Redux, when should I use each one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49568073/2873538)

Answer (score 2):

For my latest app, once global state became overwhelmingly large and complex, I decided to use Redux and Redux Toolkit to separate concerns and:

- pinpoint state variables in components with the `useSelector` hook
- write mutating state logic in reducers (`state.variable = something`)
- use awesome dev tools to 'rewind' state updates and trace actions to their source

I think use cases vary immensely.  For instances where you just need to grab some value from up the tree, `Context` works great.

Read the docs on both and you will be better able to decide which is appropriate.

Comment: I'm new so I can't like your comment, but thanks for the reply that is helpful info.